# Cannot set property 'http' of undefined - Angular Unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am fairly new to unit testing. I am building an Angular component and my test suite is Jasmine/Karma.

My first test is complaining about two issues and I'm only trying to test an initialised variable value:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'http' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isView' of undefined
```

The code is pretty simple so wondering why I'm getting these errors?

**myComponent.ts**

```
sView = false;
```

**myComponent.spec.ts**

```
describe('myComponent', () => {
    let component: myComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            declarations: [myComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: myService,
                    useFactory: myServiceMock
                }
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });


    it('isView defaults to: false', () => {
        expect(component.isView).toEqual(false);
    });

});
```

What is going on here?

Comment: can you put the myComponent code as well.

Comment: @AnoopRajasekharaWarrier sView = false; is pretty much the only thing going on.

Comment: Just to confirm if every thing okay, can you try it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }); brfore the it() statement you have.

Comment: Is it passing?  it('should create', () => { expect(component).toBeTruthy(); });

Comment: Same http issue and "Expected undefined to be truthy."

Comment: This means you are missing some thing. Share the Component I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
describe('myComponent', () => {
component: myComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;
let myServiceMock: MyServiceMock;
beforeEach(async(() => {
  myServiceMock = new MyServiceMock();
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [myComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: myService, useValue: myServiceMock }
  ]
})
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
});

beforeEach(() => {
 component.ngOnInit();
})

it('should create the app component', () => {
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

Comment: myComponent should be your Component Class Name, MyServieMock is the mock service, and myService is your Service class name

Comment: There might be spelling mistake.Please give actual class name you have

Comment: If I take away the providers the http errors disappears, what can this mean?